# Merge multiple connection strings and models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, connection-string

In an ASP.NET MVC project I'm currently working on there are multiple connection strings sharing the same information (approximately 40 strings which could be stored in 8 or so). Similarly, there are many models which could be grouped together had there been more planning.

Is there a tool, process or recommended procedure for merging these into something more manageable?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Repository Pattern Unit of Work Concept where you can define all repository methods by instantiating respective DbContext. For more information please have look at the following link.
[https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern][1].